# Lync application without lync client

Tags: c#, lync, lync-client-sdk

I was wondering if it's possible to create a Lync application to chat or call other users with the Lync SDK, but without the Lync client, and if it can be done.

I would appreciate some help.

Hope you can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lync SDK need Lync Client.
If you want to create such application try to use UCMA

Answer (score 1):

Lync SDK is kind like a wrapper of the Lync client application. It can't work alone without the Lync client.

The reason is about how Lync SDK works. Lync SDK calls the functions exposed by the Lync client process to do all its works, itself doesn't have any ability to do sip communication directly with Lync server. Lync client process acts as a COM server and Lync SDK app process acts as a COM client, they do cross-process communication by using this COM based interface.

If you are not keen to use Lync client SDK, several options for you:

1. Use UCMA. It deals with Lync server directly by using sip just like what Lync client does. It can achieve almost all features that a Lync client can do.  What's more, in some areas it provides more powerful features like impersonation, application endpoint, streaming handling. 
   Maybe a drawback of using UCMA is you need to install UCMA SDK on local machine.
   Maybe another drawback as a personal idea is UCMA has quite a few unacceptable bugs.
2. Use UCWA. It's a web service introduced from Lync server 2013. Because it's web service so it's up to you if you want to implement B/S, C/S, Windows/Linux or even mobile application.
   The drawback is the limited features it provides.
3. Though not recommended, but it's also possible to implement your own sip client if you are expert on how sip/Lync works.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way would be top use Lync UCWA as outlined here https://ucwa.lync.com/about/about-ucwa, although the functionality of the API is  currently somewhat limited.